# Simple FB Connect, whitelist issue

Tags: facebook, drupal-8, whitelist, fbconnect

I'm trying to create a Facebook login redirect via Drupal 8's Simple FB Connect module. My return URI = https://www.iquu.jobs/mijniquu/simple-fb-connect/return

I have tested this in the Redirect URI Validator and it says: This is a valid redirect URI for this application - so I guess this should okay.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNMwG.png

But for some reason when clicking the Facebook login button on my website I still get this error:

> URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not >whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web >OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect >URIs.

***Additional note:***
I'm using the Rename Admin Paths module to redirect /user to /mijniquu.

Comment: _“My return URI = ...”_ - that is not what your screenshot shows.

Comment: https://www.iquu.jobs/mijniquu/simple-fb-connect/return = My redirect/return URI (validate approves both with '/' and without '/')

Comment: _“validate approves both with '/' and without '/'”_ - that only means that both _would be_ valid, but it doesn’t mean that you can specify one and then use the other. These need to be _exact_ matches.

Comment: @misorude both links are exact the same. See screenshot: https://imgur.com/JBCMEpj

Comment: Do you get this when the login dialog is supposed to be shown, or in the step after that, when you system makes the API call to exchange the code for a token? Do you have app domains and website settings configured correctly as well?

Comment: The error pops up when you visit Facebook, this is the link:

https://www.facebook.com/v3.2/dialog/oauth?client_id=1744376992351765&state=7e471f90c8b6f1cf860361ab11cb14aa&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.6.3&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iquu.jobs%2Fnl%2Fmijniquu%2Fsimple-fb-connect%2Freturn&scope=public_profile%2Cemail%2Cpublic_profile

The settings on Drupal:
https://i.imgur.com/DhZ0VBJ.png

The settings in the Facebook app:
https://i.imgur.com/WFqqsvt.png

Because I use the Rename Admin Paths /user has been changed to /mijniquu. So I had to edit the URL from the redirect URI.

Comment: _“this is the link:”_ - the value of the redirect_uri parameter in that is _not_ what you specified in your app settings.

Comment: Problem solved, forget the /nl prefix in the uri - thanks!